# better way to search in all data if user doesnt select any group

Tags: c#, search, optimization

this is the situation:

1) if user select a News group, then enter title of News in textbox
the method will search in News where GroupId=blahblahblah

2) if user doesn't select any Group, the method will search All News

```
public List<tbl> SerchNewsByTitle(string title, int groupid)
{
    try
    {
        var result = from n in tbl   
                     where n.GroupId == groupid 
                     select n;
        if (groupid== -1)
        {
            result = from n in tbl selec n;
        }

        return result.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        AddExceptionData(e);
        return null;
    }

}
```

as you can see I pass -1 if user doesn't select a group

someone said to me by passing -1 and that if statement you Eliminating Integrity and consistency.

could you please tell me how to wrote this code in better way?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is a news item required to be grouped? If you can have a news item in your database that doesn't have an assigned group, passing a -1 value to indicate search all may be confusing. Someone could interpret it as either "Search All News" or "Search All News without an Assigned Group"

Also, as far as integrity goes, there is a line of thought that an integer ID should support the complete set of values available and excluding negative numbers would be inconsistent. If the backing database column is type int, negative values would be valid. However, in practice this view is a contentious topic that some people agree on and others do not.

I would at least create two methods so that any code that is using the methods has to know less about the underlying database. That way it wouldn't have to know any magic numbers to Search all vs search a specific group.

```
public List<tbl> SearchNewsByTitle(string title, int groupid)
{
    try
    {
        var result = from n in tbl   
                     where (n.GroupId == (groupid < 0 ? n.GroupId : groupId))
                     select n;

        return result.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        AddExceptionData(e);
        return null;
    }

}

public List<tbl> SearchNewsByTitle(string title) 
{
    return SearchNewsByTitle(title, -1);
}
```

Comment: Yes, all news Items must have an positive  int groupid, but user can avoid selecting group when search, in that case we must search in all news

Comment: Is It better to pass an enum or const instead of - 1 to indicate user has not selected a news group? For example searchtypeenum. Allnews

Comment: I marked it as answer because of removing if part, but still wonder how can we eliminate -1 and use something more readable and understandable for others as soon as he/she see the method?